# her car almost hit an old lady

Tags: sentence-construction

> A couple of days ago **her car almost hit an old lady** while she was driving and talking on the phone with her friend Clair.

Could you say this sentence sounds idiomatic? Is it idiomatic to say "her car almost hit somebody/something"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one context where this phrase ("her car almost hit someone") would sound natural, but it's not the context you want.

*Her car almost hit someone* implies that the car was under its own control, rather than being driven by someone.  For example, this is a possible use of the phrase:

*When she parked her car, she left it in neutral and didn't set the parking brake.  After she got out of the car, it started to roll down the hill.  Rolling down the hill, with no one behind the wheel, her car almost his an old lady.*

But this is quite different from the context you provided.  If someone was driving the car - even if she was distracted by talking on the phone - you'd need to say, "A couple of days ago **she almost hit an old lady with her car**."

Comment: @Sergei The general principle here is that the subject of the sentence is usually the person rather than the tool that they used. One exception is when you want to call attention to the tool specifically: "I almost hit an old lady. As it was, my side-view mirror hit her walker."